# Coq case analysis and rewrite with function returning subset types

Tags: types, case, subset, analysis, coq

I was working is this simple exercise about writing certified function using subset types. The idea is to first write a predecessor function

```
pred : forall  (n : {n : nat | n > 0}), {m : nat | S m = n.1}.
```

and then using this definition give a funtion

```
pred2 : forall (n : {n : nat | n > 1}), {m : nat | S (S m) = n.1}.
```

I have no problem with the first one. Here is my code

```
Program Definition pred (n : {n : nat | n > 0}) : {m : nat | S m = n.1} :=
  match n with
  | O => _
  | S n' => n'
  end.
Next Obligation. elimtype False. compute in H. inversion H. Qed.
```

But I cannot workout the second definition. I trying to write these definition

```
Program Definition pred2 (n : {n : nat | n > 1}) : {m : nat | S (S m) = n.1} 
:= pred (pred n).
```

I managed to prove the two first obligations

```
Next Obligation. apply (gt_trans n 1 0). assumption. auto. Qed.
Next Obligation. 
  destruct pred.  
  simpl.
  simpl in e. 
  rewrite <- e in H.
  apply gt_S_n in H; assumption.
Qed.
```

But for the last obligation I get stuck because when I try to do a case analysis for the return type of pred the new hypotesis are not rewrited in the goal.

I tried the following tactics with no results.

```
destruct (pred (n: pred2_obligation_1 (n ; H))).

destruct (pred (n; pred2_obligation_1 (n ; H))) eqn:?.
rewrite Heqs.
```

I know that I can with write pred2 directly, but the idea is to use and compose the function pred.

Comment: I am interested in the set of exercises you have there. Are they available on the web somewhere? Can you post a link or google search terms?

Comment: I'm doing this exercises http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `destruct` doesn't have any effect is probably because what you're trying to do case analysis on doesn't occur in the goal. The implicit arguments of that term probably don't match the implicit arguments of the term in the goal. Either way, you can't do case analysis on that term without making the goal ill-typed.

But you can prove that obligation by case analysis on `n`.

```
Next Obligation.
destruct n.
inversion H.
destruct n.
inversion H.
subst.
inversion H1.
cbn.
eauto.
Qed.
```

I was also able to prove some helper theorems, but I wasn't able to use them because of all the type dependency.

```
Theorem T1 : forall s1, S (` (pred s1)) = ` s1.
Proof. intros [[| n1] H1]. inversion H1. cbn. eauto. Qed.

Theorem T2 : forall T1 (P1 : T1 -> Prop) s1 H1, (forall x1 (H1 H2 : P1 x1), H1 = H2) -> exist P1 (` s1) H1 = s1.
Proof. intros ? ? [x1 H1] H2 H3. cbn in *. rewrite (H3 _ H1 H2). eauto. Qed.
```

I had never seen `destruct` used on a function. I'm surprised Coq doesn't complain that that function isn't inductively defined.

Comment: Thanks I think doing case analysis on n is a better aproach. However I still don't understand why my  aproach doesn't work. When you use destruct on a function it does case analysis in the return value of the function. When I define the function using refine

   " Definition pred2 (n : {n : nat | n > 1}) : {m : nat | S (S m) = n.1}.
  refine ((( pred ((pred (n.1 ; _)).1  ; _ )).1  ;  _ )). "

it works perfectly

Comment: Here is the proof I use.   "destruct n.
  apply (gt_trans x 1 0). assumption. auto.
  destruct n.
  destruct pred. simpl. simpl in e. rewrite <- e in g. apply gt_S_n in g. assumption.
  destruct n.
  simpl. destruct pred. destruct pred. simpl. simpl in e0. simpl in e. subst. reflexivity. "

Comment: @NicoLehmann The term `pred (n; pred2_obligation_1 (n; H))` in the conclusion and the term `pred (n; pred2_obligation_1 (n; H))` you're trying to destruct are different. To see this, turn off all notations. The term in the conclusion involves `gt`, while the term you're trying to destruct involves `lt`. Either way, you can't destruct it because `pred2_obligation_2 (n; H)` depends on it.