# Coq tutorial and/or book with exercises involving subset types

Tags: coq

Is there a Coq tutorial and/or book with discussion and exercises involving subset types, as in the following SO question?

[Coq case analysis and rewrite with function returning subset types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178128/coq-case-analysis-and-rewrite-with-function-returning-subset-types)

It doesn't have to be that set of exercises specifically, but I am interested in learning how to use subset types.

Comment: Well, maybe that rule makes sense for "which book should I learn C from" questions but this question is so narrow that I doubt it would attract "opinionated answers and spam".

Comment: Matthieu Sozeau has [a whole section of his website](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~sozeau/research/russell.en.html) dedicated to this.

Comment: Yeah, I remember looking at that ages ago when I first tried to learn certified programming in Coq, but all the links to examples yield 404. Especially the quicksort example would've been nice to have, since I don't necessarily want to have to learn about the invariants of whatever "finger trees" are (sounds complicated) just to gain an understanding of dependent/subset types.

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved, the exercises were from Homeworks from [CIS 670](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/) at Penn in Fall 2012, which is linked from the website for the CPDT book, and they are related to a chapter from CPDT that deals with subset types.

Answer (score 1):

Subsets (`sig`) are defined inductively. They pair an object and a proof about that object. They're similar to `ex` but reside in `Set`/`Type` instead of `Prop`. There's also a `sigT`.

```
Print ex.
Print sig.
Print sigT.
```

The `Program` command allows you to ignore the proofs that come bundled in subsets and to build those proofs interactively after the function is defined. There's a [chapter](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual026.html) about the `Program` command in the manual. Be aware though that links to the manual are ever changing.

Comment: Well, hats off to anyone who can get the hang of this stuff just by examining the output of those `Print` statements. The rest of us need more explanation and exercises to work through ;) I am about 1/2 way through the CPDT chapter and HW8 exercises right now ...